# Scala sorted map does not have methods floor or ceil

Tags: scala, collections

I'm new to Scala but now I want to use `scala.collection.SortedMap` to retreive the floor. I mean something like this:

```
val m = SortedMap[Long, String]()

def retreiveAndProcess(l: Long) = {
    val floor = // get the floor of l to m
    //do some with floor
}
```

Comment: What do you mean with floor? The map-entry with the key you provide as parameter?

Comment: @ThomasBöhm I mean the closest key that is less then the parameter

Answer (score 5):

You can do what you want using `from`, `until` and `to` which can be found on `Sorted` and declare that they return a ranged *projection* **[1]** of the collection:

```
m.to(l).lastKey    //floor

m.from(l).firstKey //ceil
```

You will have to check for emptiness as these will throw `NoSuchElementException`s. I would generally add some useful utilities using implicit conversions:

```
scala> implicit class SortedMapOps[K, V](val m: SortedMap[K, V]) extends AnyVal {
     |   def floor(k: K): Option[(K, V)] = {
     |     val n = m.to(k)
     |     //You could just use n.lastOption here
     |     if (n.isEmpty) None
     |     else Some((n.lastKey, n(n.lastKey)))
     |   }
     | }
defined class SortedMapOps
```

Then:

```
scala> SortedMap(1 -> "a", 2 -> "b", 3 -> "c", 5 -> "e")
res2: scala.collection.immutable.SortedMap[Int,String] = Map(1 -> a, 2 -> b, 3 -> c, 5 -> e)

scala> res2.floor(4)
res3: Option[(Int, String)] = Some((3,c))
```

**[1]** - The implication being that this is `O(1)`, (or at least *not* `O(N)`)

Comment: Why not simply `range(lo, hi)`?